# ¿Existe un for in para PHP?

Tags: php, json, objeto

Estoy trabajando con objetos en PHP. Lo que busco es imprimir en php el objeto (propiedades y valores) sin tener que escribir cada propiedad. Busco una especie de for-in para PHP. He probado con get_object_vars, pero no es lo mismo.
Gracias por sus respuestas.

//perro.json

```
{
"nombre":"Kesha",
"raza":"poodle",
"edad":10
}
```

//documento php

```
$perro3=file_get_contents('js/perro.json');
$perro4=json_decode($perro3,false);

print_r(get_object_vars($perro4));
```

Comment: ¿Con [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) no logras algo similar?

Comment: ¿Para qué lo quieres imprimir? ¿Es para el usuario o para ti (depuración o bitácora)? ¿O te interesa mas recorrer el arreglo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar con foreach, teniendo en cuenta tu código quedaría algo así:

```
$perro3 = file_get_contents('js/perro.json');

$perro4 = json_decode($perro3, false);

foreach ($perro4 as $propiedad => $valor) {
    echo "$propiedad: $valor<br>";
}
```

Comment: Sí, ese es el código.